# HiQPdf Cannot get the executing assembly directory

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, hiqpdf

When I try to convert html to PDF using HiQPdf on Linux (on Windows works ok) I get this error:

```
Something went wrong: System.Exception: Cannot get the executing assembly directory. Empty directory
   at hiqpdfimpl.ᤤ..ctor(ᤣ A_0)
   at HiQPdf.HtmlToImage.ᜀ(String A_0, String A_1, String A_2, ᣩ& A_3, Hashtable& A_4)
   at HiQPdf.HtmlToPdf.ᜀ(String A_0, String A_1, String A_2, String A_3, Boolean A_4)
   at HiQPdf.HtmlToPdf.ᜀ(Stream A_0, String A_1, String A_2, String A_3, String A_4, Boolean A_5)
   at HiQPdf.HtmlToPdf.ᜁ(String A_0, String A_1, String A_2, String A_3, Boolean A_4)
   at HiQPdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertHtmlToMemory(String html, String baseUrl)
```

Comment: Hello. It certainly does not work in Linux for me either with the same error message. I also sent an e-mail to their support over a month ago with no reply. They don't seem to care.

Comment: I received reply from support confirming that Linux isn't supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working on Linux starting from .NET Core.
First of all you must get rid of `System.Drawing.Common` in your code because now [it's only supported on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only). You can use [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp), [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp) or [Microsoft.Maui.Graphics](https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics) instead. All of them are cross-platform.

Then, install `libgdiplus`.

On ubuntu:
`sudo apt-get install -y libgdiplus`

On macOs (homebrew must be installed in your system):
`brew install mono-libgdiplus`

Restart Nginx server:
`sudo systemctl restart nginx`

If the problem is still there, open terminal in project folder and make

`nuget restore <Your-project-or.sln>`

Comment: the hiqpdf netcore library still references system.drawing.common so how could we possibly get rid of it?